# Cannot open a file/drawable in Android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am trying to apply a git patch in Android studio and always the get stuck. I have to kill the android studio (Happens the same if I want to import a drawable).

I am using MacOS Monterrey 12.4

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 28, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.6.21-release-334-AS5457.46)

Looks like an issue between mac and android studio file selector.

Any ideas/workaround?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found that this happens only I try to access file in Desktop able to import drawable from other locations.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1 on macOS 12.4. Every time the macOS file picker was started Android Studio froze and wasn't usable anymore.

I could only solve it by downgrading to Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) Patch 3 which can be downloaded here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

(I also cleared the Android Studio folders in `~/Library/Application Support/Google` but I'm not sure if that was necessary to resolve the problem.)

**Update**: I found a similar bug ticket here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239767509